# Number of stereoisomers of 1,3,5-trimethylcyclohexane

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers, cyclohexane

When I searched the stereoisomers of 1,3,5-trimethylcyclohexane, I got four structures given below.

[image: stereoisomers of 1,3,5-trimethylcyclohexane]

I don't get how structures **1** and **2**, **3**, and **4** are not the same. Could anyone explain?

Comment: 1 and 2 are the same all right.

Comment: @IvanNeretin what about 3 and 4 how are they different if we just turn the ring upside down?

Comment: They aren't different either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1,3,5-Trimethylcyclohexane doe not show optical isomerism as it has no chiral carbon atoms. Therefore, we are left with counting the total number of *cis*–*trans* isomers.

1,3,5-Trimethylcyclohexane has two *cis*–*trans* isomers which are given by structures **1** and **3** in your diagram.

**1** and **2** are identical because if you look from behind the plane of the screen, **1** will turn into **2**. Similar argument holds for **3** and **4**. Hence we get two distinct *cis*–*trans* isomers.

Comment: They are conformational isomers e,e,e and a,a,a  and  a,e,e and e,a,a. So it depends on temperature. Molecules are 3-dimensional.